# Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-typeahead

I am using the type ahead address picker given [here](https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker)

1) Have included google map and typeahead. Jquery is added through a gem and referenced in application.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-US"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker/master/dist/typeahead-addresspicker.js"></script>
```

2)Have added input text

```
<input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter an address">
```

3)Have instantiated address picker and typeahead.

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    var addressPicker = new AddressPicker();

             $('#address').typeahead(null, {
                              displayKey: 'description',
                              source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
              });

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Issue was resolved [here](https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker/issues/30)

> You should include typeahead.bundle.js which has typeahead +
> bloodhound. Look at demo here
> https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/, they include
> https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js

Needed to include https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js
for typeahead + bloodhound, which fixed the issue.